# Could I use a front rim to build a rear wheel?

Tags: wheels, rims, wheel-building

Could I build a rear wheel using a front rim?

---

Edit: Follow-on question [Spokes stick out of nipples when rebuilding wheel](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/61854/spokes-stick-out-of-nipples-when-rebuilding-wheel/) reusing spokes.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think the answer is: it depends. The major difference will be spoke counts, how many spokes on the front and how many on the rear? Why do you need to use a front rim, is it just a spare you have around?

Comment: Are the rear hub and spokes re-useable, and do the rims match in hole-count and manufacturer & model?

Comment: Would not re-use spokes, you never really know what they have suffered during their life time.

Answer (score 15):

In the days before factory built wheelset, rims where produced without being specifically for front or rear wheels. On most general-use standard bicycles it is still that way. The only difference was the spoke-hole count.

But many rear wheel rims today are no longer symmetrical, meaning the right side is different from the left. This is mainly due to the fact that with 11 or even 12 speed cassettes the dish of the wheel is very unsymmetrical and the angle at which the spokes reach the rim makes the spokes puts a lot of pull on the rim. This is being countered by positioning the spoke holes differently for the drive or non-drive side.

Although 36 holes was and still is the normal count on most bicycles, you could build wheels with 32 or 28 spokes, those being mostly used on front wheels, mostly for weight saving or aerodynamics.

Nowadays many rims are specialised for their use and designed for front or rear wheels in mind, mostly for aerodynamic or load bearing abilities and often with different spoke counts. Although with the advent of disc brakes the spoke count on many front wheels is on the rise. Disc brakes put about the same stress on front wheel as the drive puts on the rear.

But if you use one of the many 'standard' rims that are still in production, you may build a rear or front wheel with any rim.

Side-note: In the old days also front wheels would be built with thinner often double-butted spokes (1.5-1.2-1.5mm), while rear wheels had thicker (2mm) straight spokes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but, it's a lot of work and you should consider whether it is cheaper/easier to buy a rear wheel already built.

Wheel building is a skilled job and does require tools most people don't own and or wouldn't be cost effective to purchase for a one off wheel build, which I can only assume this is. Not to mention the fact that if op does not know whether it is possible to build a wheel up as a front or rear shows they are not trained in wheel building. That's no big deal. Most people couldn't build a wheel myself included.

So basically don't get in to a specialised job if you lack basic knowledge. In simple terms wheels are available cheaply online, ready built by a trained specialist. This is a far easier and cost effective solution than buying all the tools and parts then learning to build a wheel.

Comment: This is more an opinion than an answer to the actual question.  Further it is an *uninformed* opinion, as you admit you've never actually tried to build a wheel.  Speaking as someone who has (after receiving uniform encouragement from others who have), it's an accomplishable and rewarding project, and does not actually require much in the way of equipment investment - all I actually bought for the project was a spoke wrench.  And what you end up with is far better than a cheap machine built wheel.

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove the "probably" and to put the emphasis on the OP deciding for themselves. I hope that's ok and doesn't change the meaning of your answer significantly, you can always rollback to the original. It seemed constructive in light of Chris's comment.

Comment: No truing gauge required then? No specific knowledge or pattern to tighten the spokes in or previous experience of tension on the spokes. I am not saying it can't be done by someone attempting it for the first time I was suggesting a cheap easy fix. Comparably buying a cheap wheel is a easier solution than building one for the average person. That's fact not opinion.

Comment: A set of spokes, a hub and a spoke wrench would cost more than a built wheel imo. Not to mention the time put in to building it and I am guessing you would suggest making a jig or truing stand that's more time spent. Over all for a quick cheap fix buying a wheel is easier than building one that's my point.

Comment: *Wheel building is a highly skilled job and does require specific tools most people don't own and or wouldn't be cost effective to purchase for a one off wheel build*  All you really need is a good spoke wrench. Truing stand? Hold the hub and spin it. You'll be able to tell if it's true. Proper dish? Lay flat on the floor, push the rim to the floor at one point. Note how high on a table leg/wall/etc the highest point of the rim is. Flip wheel over, repeat. When the height is the same from both sides, the wheel is properly dished. Done.

Comment: That's sounds really easy and accurate ! So buy a good spoke wrench some spokes and a hub. Run in to problems straight away through inexperience which is the case for op. Hence his immediate further questions running into difficulties with spoke length. Which brings me back to my initial point if you lack basic knowledge of this subject you will probably struggle with this project. Therefor it's much cheaper and easier to buy a built wheel. However I never said he couldn't or shouldn't build the wheel I just stated what I thought would be easier or more cost effective imo.  *opinion only*

Comment: David your answer is fine, you don’t have to engage with commenters any further. They should know better that comments are to ask for more information or suggest improvements, not suggest you change the meaning of your answer. If people agree with your answer and think it is well written they will upvote it. If people don’t then they won’t. That’s how the system works after all.

Comment: @swifty True, thanks for the advice. I am a newbie here after all. All good advice is appreciated and taken on board.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Easier said than done, especially for a newbie who’ll need a lot of twiddling to get it true. Without a spoke tensiometer it’s also hard to gauge tension. I built my first wheelset directly in the bicycle, using the brakes as a guide. Wouldn’t really recommend.

Comment: @Michael The problem is this answer is worded as a statement-of-fact:  *"Wheel building is a highly skilled job and does require specific tools ..."*  Ummm, no.  "Highly skilled" is highly subjective, and I personally don't think wheelbuilding requires anything more than basic mechanical skills and patience.  I posted my comment to point out that those "specific tools" are, quite simply, not required.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with standard wheels the front and rear rims are identical. Just make sure the number of spoke holes of the rim matches your rear hub. Sometimes they use fewer spokes on the front. Some manufacturers offer asymmetric rims for the rear wheel (because a rear hub with cassette is inherently asymmetric) but you could still use a normal, symmetric rim.

Some proprietary wheel sets have other asymmetries and complex lacing patterns, but I assume you are not asking about one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can **if** the rims themselves are both symmetric.

And, give it a try. Don't listen to the nay-sayers. Some people are so risk averse, I'm surprised they leave their houses in the morning.

What's the worst that could happen?  This isn't amputating your leg.  It's just a wheel. Bust a spoke? $2/each.  Have to buy a spoke wrench? $10 used.  Over tighten/strip a spoke nipple $0.50 for a new one.

You have to really try to damage the hub, or the rim.  If it doesn't work, then take it all apart and try again, or work it 90% of the way and then take it to the LBS and let them 'true' the wheel for $20.  You'll have learned something. You'll be more confident when out on your bike.  You'll know what to do if you're on the trail and a buddy has a loose spoke.  All good things, now you know something more about this great hobby, and that makes it more fun.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to bicycles.stackexchange. This question is almost two years old and has several answers that are essentially the same. There are plenty of newer and unanswered questions, perhaps you'd like to have a look at them.