# Spokes stick out of nipples when rebuilding wheel

Tags: wheels, wheel-building

I'm having issues with the nipples the spoke threads are sticking out. I want to tension the wheel but when I tighten the nipples the spoke treads come out from top of the nipples before the wheel is tensioned completely.

---

Edit: Related to, and following on from [Could I use a front rim to build a rear wheel?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/61846/could-i-use-a-front-rim-to-build-a-rear-wheel)

Comment: You may need spokes of a different length. Check the diameter of the flanges of the rear hub and compare to those of the front hub.

Comment: Where did the spokes come from? What is the ERD of the old rim and the new rim? Are you using the same rear hub or a new one? Is the problem with all the spokes or just on one side? Is either rim asymmetrically drilled?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93585/discussion-on-question-by-alfredo-suarez-spokes-stick-out-of-nipples-when-rebuil).

Answer (score 5):

It seems the spokes are too long. Two possibilities I can think of:

a) If the rim had been built into a front wheel before, and you are using the same spokes, it's possible that the rear and front hubs have dimensions different enough that the recommended 2 mm margin of error on spoke length is insufficient. The main variable affecting spoke length (besides the ERD, but here I'm assuming the rim stays constant) will be the flange radius (1 mm less means about 1 mm less on radial builds with a smaller difference the more crossings you have), but a big difference in the flange offset from the center of the hub can have a significant impact as well. Use a spoke calculator.

b) you're doing a different number of crossings. This will affect the the required spoke length bigly.

Comment: Or the more glaring issue - most rear wheels are dished (hub not centered) to account for the sprockets.

Comment: In factories they deal with this by grinding away the end of the spoke after the wheel has been assembled.

Comment: Sources? For manufacturer it would be easier to order or cut correct length and avoid this extra step.

Comment: The asker's original title which was unhelpfully removed by a confused 3rd party made it clear that they were trying to re-use front wheel components to build a rear wheel.  That leads to multiple causes for the spoke lengths to be wrong.  Spokes are relatively cheap and using new ones has advantages even beyond proper fit.

Comment: @ChrisStratton we're not yet confirmed that the spokes were reused, but it does seem probable.

Comment: @ojs - My "source" is having seen the inside of many wheels.  It's not at all unusual to see the evidence of a grinder being applied to the nipple and spoke end.  I suspect that for some manufacturers it's easier to just grind the spokes to length rather than fussily manage their spoke inventory.

Comment: I have filed plenty of spoke ends when fine-tuning wheels.  Sometimes its because a replacement spoke was too long but nothing else was available.  Either by hand-filing, or by using a dremel-style tool.  I'd not get the 4 inch angle-grinder out.

Comment: @Criggie But by filing spokes that are too long, part of the thread of the spoke will be lost, so possibly the spoke won't be as secured. I've just measured a sapim spoke and a standard 12mm DT swiss nipple and the spoke has 9 mm of thread, while the nipple has 7.4. So by having more than 1.6 mm sticking out of the nipple (including the last 1 mm on the top of the nipple where the slit lies), you're already not fully engaging the nipple.

Comment: @Artefacto yes, that sounds about right.  Threadding the nipple onto the spoke too far like this would also increase the risk of breaking the spoke at the nipple.

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution here is to get some accurate vernier calipers and measure the rim and hub dimensions, then feed them into a calculator.

Some useful spoke calcs I've used include

- https://leonard.io/edd/  and https://leonard.io/edd/howtomeasure
- http://wheelspoking.com/Build.aspx?Mode=Basic

Basically feed the same numbers into each and you should get the same/similar answers.

Then measure your existing spokes, which will all be the same length because they're from a front wheel.  The rear wheel should have a ~1-3mm difference between their lengths per side.

Comment: Those existing wrong length spokes can be a useful aid in measuring the critical ERD of the rim as the first step towards calculating and ordering correct ones.  With the hub and all other spokes removed OP can measure between spokes positioned as desired in opposite nipples and then add the measured length of the two spokes.  With a used rim take several measurements as it may no longer be entirely round on its own.